# Cannot create new user account Windows Server 2012

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012, user-management

I created a Windows Domain account that works on `MYDOMAIN`. All computers attached to `MYDOMAIN` can use the credentials I have created for log on except for one.

On `PROBLEMSERVER01` when I try to log in with `MYDOMAIN` \ `myuser` I get the following error (other accounts previously created are working):

> User Profile Service service failed the sign-in.
>
> User Profile cannot be loaded.
>
> OK

When I log on to the server and check C:\Users I do not see a folder associated with the account I created. When I check each registry's  `S-1-5` folders under the the `ProfileImagePath` entry there is no entry for my user. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215

If I try to create the account locally on the machine it appears to work upon creation (no errors there), but if I try to log in I get the same message and no entries are added to the registry.

> User Profile Service service failed the sign-in.
>
> User Profile cannot be loaded.
>
> OK

Event log data after trying to sign in:

> User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program
>
> User Logon Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program
>
> The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the stopped state
>
> The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the running state
>
> A LDAP connection with domain controller DC01.MYDOMAIN.localhost for
> domain MYDOMAIN is established

I have also tried copying the C:\Users\Default folder from a known good server to this one with no change in results.

Comment: @RyanRies,  `ProfileList` is the parent directory that contains the S-15-XX... folders. Inside of these folders contains `ProfileImagePath` Ex. i.imgur.com/QZ4SE6p.png

Comment: Are you suggesting I delete all of the S-5-21-... sub keys?

Comment: That's the issue, there isn't one listed for the user that cannot log in.

Comment: Validate to be sure no roaming or a profile path got setuped for that user.

Comment: Does either the username or the password you've created, with the issues described, have any characters which would only be available in some localisations which are included on the rest of the server builds but not the affected? This is a long-shot but I can't think of much else which may cause what you describe

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be the issue. I even changed the password to the same as another user account that does work -- just to be sure the chars were OK.

Comment: @에이바 did you try to create other user accounts and logging in with them? It'll help differentiate between some user-specific-residue and non-user-specific issues

Comment: @Nitz, yes I created new user accounts and they also had the same issue.

Comment: Does the login problem  on this server exist with every new user you created? if i understand you right the new user 'myuser' can't log in, old users are working fine. What if you create an other new testuser? Can the new testuser log in?

Comment: @frupfrup, all existing users work as normal. Any new user that is created cannot log in.

Comment: Perhaps compare the permissions of C:\users and the likes against a working workstation?

Comment: I think this MUST be something with the C:\Users\Default folder. Try to copy it again from an blank winServer 2012 System and do a Filesize check if the Byte-number really is the same. And also check if the Filerights are correct. particularly for you C:\Users\Default folder!

Comment: Default folder has been copied and is exactly the same from a new 2012 system. Issue persists.

Comment: Sysinternals procmon.exe has an option for boot logging. You might be able to use it to catch the problem as it happens during the login process.

Comment: @에이바 & Jason No need for boot logging in this case (because login happens later), just log in with admin, and filter the results by user.

Comment: OS not mentioned?? Can you please specify..?

Comment: What does a "GPRESULT /R" on this sever give you for the user parameters ? This is maybe not related but I once had a similar issue because two computer had the same name in my domain....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Server 2012 R2 with April 2014 update ([KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355)) and also seeing Event ID 1500 in Application log ("Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, and that your network is functioning correctly.") as well as Event ID 1509 ("Windows cannot copy file \?\UNC\contoso.com\Users\Profiles\User1.V4\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\Program Settings\0000.ex to location \?\C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\Program Settings\0000.ex. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.") then it is known issue with available coldfix from Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2985344

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try in a situation like this is to remove the computer/server from the domain.

Reboot computer/server.

Delete the computer account in the domain.

Add the computer/server back to the domain again.

Reboot the computer/server.

Login and be happy.